# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 27648000 into shape (2400,1280,3)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

here I have a small project on which I block for weeks

I Have a display is 3840x2400 monochrome pixels. Nevertheless, it is driven like 1280(RGB)x2400, whereas each RGB subpixel maps to one monochrome pixel.

Therefore, in order to display real 3840x2400 one has to map 3 consecutive pixels of the monochrome image to one pseudo-RGB pixel. This yields a 1280x2400 wide image, where each RGB subpixel corresponds to one real monochrome pixel.

I try to do this in python3.9 with numpy and PIL

The code below:

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

def TransTo1224(SourcePngFileName, DestPngFileName):
  #trans png file from 3840x2400 to 1280X2400(RGB)
  print('~~~~~~~')
  print(SourcePngFileName)
  imgSrc = Image.open(SourcePngFileName)
  dataSrc = np.array(imgSrc)
  dataDest = dataSrc.reshape(2400,1280,3)
  imgDest = Image.fromarray(dataDest, 'RGB')
  imgDest.save(DestPngFileName)


TransTo1224("./source/test1.png","./output/test1.png")
```

I have a error:

```
dataDest = dataSrc.reshape(2400,1280,3)
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 27648000 into shape (2400,1280,3)
```

I don't understand my mistake, if someone can help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: Seems like the dimensions of the source PNG are wrong. 3840x2400x1 = 9216000. Not 27648000. Try printing out the dimensions of dataSrc. FYI, reshape can only rearrange matrices that have the same total number of elements. It cannot combine 3 RBG values into one monochrome value.

Comment: Hello @hasdrubal thank you for your answer I just tried print(imgSrc.size) and I have (3840, 2400)

Comment: 27648000 is `3840*1280*3`.  You can't use `numpy` reshape` to change the size of an image.  You have to use an `Image` `resize` method.

Comment: Hello @hpaulj , yes I want to remap an image 3840x2400 to reshape(2400,1280,3), I found my problem was the mode of my input image that was in RGB instead of L

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
dataDest = vv.reshape(2400,1280,3,-1)
```

or

```
dataDest = vv.reshape(2400,1280,3,3)
```

using dataDest = dataSrc.reshape(2400,1280,3) it wont work

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have just tried the two solutions that you have proposed and I also have an error raise ValueError(f"Too many dimensions: {ndim} > {ndmax}.")  ValueError: Too many dimensions: 4 > 3.

Comment: He's not trying to reshape an array, but rather resize an image.

Answer (score 0):

ok i solved my problem it came indeed from my input image, the code works with some images but not the one i want to remap. besides i didn't understand where this multiple of 3 came from the
3840x2400x3 = 27648000.

Well my problem came from the **mode** of the image which was in RGB.

it was enough for me to convert this mode in "L", luminance before making my reshape

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

def TransTo1224(SourcePngFileName, DestPngFileName):
  #trans png file from 3840x2400 to 1280X2400(RGB)
  print('~~~~~~~')
  print(SourcePngFileName)
  imgSrc = Image.open(SourcePngFileName)
  imgSrc = imgSrc.convert('L') # <-----
  dataSrc = np.array(imgSrc)
  dataDest = dataSrc.reshape(2400,1280,3)
  imgDest = Image.fromarray(dataDest, 'RGB')
  imgDest.save(DestPngFileName)

TransTo1224("./source/test1.png","./output/test1.png")
```

Thank you all for helping me